# How to map cache to a list of DTO object?

Tags: java, caching, modelmapper

I have this cache that is basically a list of a DTO:

ClassA:

```
@Cacheable("MyList")
public List<MyObjectDTO> setCachedList(){
return api.getList(); //call to another api to fetch that list
}
```

ClassB:

```
public List<MyObjectDTO> getCachedList(){
if(!CacheManager.getCacheNames().contains("MyList"){
   ClassB.setCachedList();
}
Cache cache = CacheManager.getCache("MyList");
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyObjectDTO>>(){}.getType(); //error occurs here
List<MyObjectDTO> returnList = modelMapper.map(cache, listType);
return returnList;
```

I get the following error in above code:

`Failed to instantiate instance of destination java.util.List. Ensure that java.util.List has a non-private no-argument constructor.`

I saw a similar question but since I am using cache of a list, I cannot extend it to concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is in the line you mention but in the one right after. Type returns `List`, but `List` is an interface and therefore impossible to instantiate, your mapper must be catching this exception and throwing the error.

You should try another way for getting the cache type, maybe `cache.getClass()` or something of the sort will do the trick.

Comment: I am new to Cache, after caching does the cache change it's class during runtime? So here during runtime cache.getClass() would return List<MyObjectDTO>?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by passing `cache.get(SimpleKey.EMPTY).get()` in the modelMapper instead of cache.